# datasourse not reading controller method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I'm new in asp.net mvc and have a problem. Datasourse can't read my jsonresult method and I'm getting no items to display

Homecontroller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();

    }
 public JsonResult GetData()
    {
        using (GridEnt db = new GridEnt())
        {
            List<Cours> courses = db.Courses.ToList();
            List<Teacher> teachers = db.Teachers.ToList();

            var courseRecord = from t in teachers
                               join c in courses on t.Id equals c.Fk_Teacher into table1
                               from c in table1.ToList()
                               select new ViewModel
                               {
                                   teacher = t,
                                   cours = c,
                               };
            //return View(courseRecord);
            return Json(courseRecord, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoUIApp.Models.ViewModel>() 
.Name("grid")
.AutoBind(true)
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.cours.Code).Title("Course Code").Filterable(false);
    columns.Bound(p => p.cours.Name).Title("Course");
    columns.Bound(p => p.cours.Language).Title("Course Language");
    columns.Bound(p => p.teacher.Name).Title("Teacher Name");
    columns.Bound(p => p.teacher.Surname).Title("Teacher Surname");
})
.Pageable()
.Sortable()
.Scrollable()
.Filterable()
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)
    .Read(read => read.Url(Url.Action("GetData", "Home", new { httproute = "" })))
 )
```

)

Comment: Try using `.Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "Home")`

Comment: Not helping.. I add more information about my added links in _Layout.cshtml file.

Comment: When you debug the `GetData` method, is any data returned?

Comment: In general the method returns required data, the problem is that during Kendo UI initialization the GetData method is not called.

Comment: @GintareMorkūnaite with `.AutoBind(true)` (which is already `true` by default) it should open a request to that url immediately after initialization. Have you checked your console's network tab for that request ?

Answer (score 0):

The kendo grid expects the result in a different format. The returned JSON should look like this:

{ total: ..., data: ...}

To achieve this you need to change you need to add a request parameter and make use of the ToDataSourceResult extension method. Your GetData method should then look like this:

```cs
    public JsonResult GetData([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        using (GridEnt db = new GridEnt())
        {
            List<Cours> courses = db.Courses.ToList();
            List<Teacher> teachers = db.Teachers.ToList();

            var courseRecord = from t in teachers
                               join c in courses on t.Id equals c.Fk_Teacher into table1
                               from c in table1.ToList()
                               select new ViewModel
                               {
                                   teacher = t,
                                   cours = c,
                               };
            //return View(courseRecord);
            return Json(courseRecord.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

The "JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet" part is only needed if you block GET request in your application.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;`

Modify your controller action as following

```
 public ActionResult GetData([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    using (GridEnt db = new GridEnt())
    {
        List<Cours> courses = db.Courses.ToList();
        List<Teacher> teachers = db.Teachers.ToList();

        var courseRecord = from t in teachers
                           join c in courses on t.Id equals c.Fk_Teacher into table1
                           from c in table1.ToList()
                           select new ViewModel
                           {
                               teacher = t,
                               cours = c,
                           };
        DataSourceResult result = courseRecord.ToDataSourceResult(request);
        var jsonResult = Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
        return jsonResult;
    }
}
```

and in view change read function to because you are not passing any parameters to action

```
.Read(read => read.Url(Url.Action("GetData", "Home")))
```

Suppose if you want to pass a parameter like shown in your question, Follow the below syntax

```
.Read(read => read.Url(Url.Action("GetData", "Home", new { httproute = "" })))
```

In Controller Action

```
 public ActionResult GetData([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request,string httproute)
  {
      //You can use `httproute`
      using (GridEnt db = new GridEnt())
      {
        List<Cours> courses = db.Courses.ToList();
        List<Teacher> teachers = db.Teachers.ToList();

        var courseRecord = from t in teachers
                       join c in courses on t.Id equals c.Fk_Teacher into table1
                       from c in table1.ToList()
                       select new ViewModel
                       {
                           teacher = t,
                           cours = c,
                       };
       DataSourceResult result = courseRecord.ToDataSourceResult(request);
      var jsonResult = Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
      jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
      return jsonResult;
    }
  }
```